# Cannot pickle 'dict_keys' object - dict validator with keysrules

Tags: python

```py
UPDATEABLE_FIELDS_KEYS = dict.fromkeys(["subject", "target"]).keys()

update_schema = {
    "internal_id": {
        "required": True,
        "type": "string",
        "regex": UUIDV4,
        "empty": False,
        "excludes": "message_code",
    },
    "message_code": {
        "required": True,
        "type": "string",
        "empty": False,
        "excludes": "internal_id",
        "coerce": to_uppercase_fn,
    },
    "fields": {
        "required": True,
        "type": "dict",
        "keysrules": {
            "required": False,
            "type": "string",
            "allowed": UPDATEABLE_FIELDS_KEYS,
        },
    },
}
```

If I validate something like this:

```
data = {
  "message_code": "ABC123",
  "fields": {
    "this_one_not_valid": "some words",
    "subject": "a thing",
    "target": "something else"
  }
}

validator = Validator(update_schema, allow_unknown=False)
validator(data)
validator.errors
```

I get this error:
`TypeError: cannot pickle 'dict_keys' object`

Am I doing something wrong here?  It works acceptably in the "correct" cases, but not when I provide an invalid key name.

Stacktrace, some words altered but the code provided above is otherwise the code I am using.

```
  File "/Users/c/Development/ub/app/blueprints/p/p.py", line 201, in update_existing
    return jsonify(validator.errors), 422
  File "/Users/c/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/ub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cerberus/validator.py", line 464, in errors
    return self.error_handler(self._errors)
  File "/Users/c/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/ub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cerberus/errors.py", line 493, in __call__
    self.extend(errors)
  File "/Users/c/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/ub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cerberus/errors.py", line 397, in extend
    self.add(error)
  File "/Users/c/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/envs/ub/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cerberus/errors.py", line 510, in add
    error = deepcopy(error)
  File "/Users/c/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/Users/c/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 269, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/Users/c/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/Users/c/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 229, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/Users/c/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/Users/c/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 229, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/Users/c/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 161, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'dict_keys' object
```

Comment: please show the full stacktrace and actual code you're using -- you're probably passing `foo.keys()` somewhere where you mean to pass `list(foo)` instead

Comment: Additional data added, but this code is essentially what I'm running, with some variables changed to protect their identity.  ‍♂️

Comment: well the code you've shared does not reproduce the error.  please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I could see this being actually broken is my guess above about `UPDATEABLE_FIELDS_KEYS`

your code is using `some_dict.keys()` to set that value which returns a keys view (`dict_keys` type in python)

adjusting the code in your question if I change:

```
-UPDATEABLE_FIELDS_KEYS = ["subject", "target"]
+UPDATEABLE_FIELDS_KEYS = dict.fromkeys(["subject", "target"]).keys()
```

I can then  reproduce the stacktrace.

The easy fix is to not call `.keys()` (the only valid case I've seen for calling `.keys()` in python is to use it as a setlike, every other case I've seen is better done as either (1) iterate over the dictionary directly or (2) use `in` for containment (3) convert to the type you want via iterator)

In this case, you probably want a list or a tuple or a set, for example:

```py
SOME_DICT = {"subject": 1, "target": 1}

UPDATEABLE_FIELDS_KEYS = frozenset(SOME_DICT)
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful insight.  This solves the problem and opened my eyes to the issues of using `.keys()` when I probably wanted something different.